# Django Override the Default success_url in contrib.auth.views

Tags: python, html, django, url, overriding

I made an app with app_name = 'accounts' in urls.py of the django and created signup/login pages there using the built-in signup function.

Now I need to change all the class details of the success_url, for instance from:

```
reverse_lazy('login')
```

to:

```
reverse_lazy('accounts:login')
```

but overwriting the original urls.py is not a good practice.
I'm a python beginner and struggling with this problem already for a month..

how can I achieve this?

What I attemptd was making subclasses in my views inherent from each of the class in django.contrib.auth.views.

I even tried putting try/except method with except 'NoReverseMatch:' but the function itself did not exist.

Comment: Where did you use `reverse_lazy('login')`? Can you give some examples?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem 'login' was used by my original class in views.py but they are usually part of the preset in django.contrib.auth.urls. like this:                  class PasswordChangeView(PasswordContextMixin, FormView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("password_change_done")
    template_name = "registration/password_change_form.html"
    title = _("Password change")

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no other solution that override django.contrib.auth classes for make your custom urls if you are using the default.

Overriding the default urls.py does not work because auth code use the original urls.

With package like django-allauth, you can make custom urls, but with Django-auth, it is not possible.
then I think it goes rather quickly to copy paste the classes of auth.views.py and to overload the different urls

I am interesting if someone else has a better and elegant solution of this problem too

Comment: How is that possible to overload a different urls.py!?

Comment: @YOUROUS i said overriding urls.py does not work so it is not possible so i do not understand your question ? You can make a different urls.py with same url name as django.contrib.auth and set in your main urls.pŷ instead of default django.contrib.auth.urls but you cannot change the name, only the path so it cannot resolve your problem

Comment: Excuse me I was asking about the django-allauth thing because it's not familiar to me, but I get it that there's no easy solution for this override stuff yet right

Comment: @YOUROUS you can find some informations on the official doc: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-redirects

Answer (score 0):

Typically the login url is specified in the [**`LOGIN_URL`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#login-url):

```
# settings.py

# …

LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('accounts:login')
```

In your views where you need the `LOGIN_URL`, you then import this from the settings, so:

```
from django.conf import settings


class PasswordChangeView(PasswordContextMixin, FormView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    success_url = settings.LOGIN_URL
    template_name = 'registration/password_change_form.html'
    title = _('Password change')
```

This thus makes it convenient to plug in a different view name.

Comment: I suppose this will also work 100%, however what I am telling here is changing all the success_url path to the app_name-related path including 'password_change_done', 'password_reset_done' and 'password_reset_complete'. I am sorry I gave you the bad example by using 'login'. Is there something also like 'PASSWORD_CHANGE_DONE_URL'?

Comment: The question is about change all defaull url of django.contrib.auth, not just LOGIN_URL